# touch and effect any object

Tags: python, kivy

...
How can I give function  path?
I couldn't find how to solve addressing.
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?
When I click on the green area only, I want to do the operation of the button in the white area.
...

'''python
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



class Area(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class Sec(RelativeLayout):
    """ This is white area """
    def chn(self):
        self.ids.secbut.disabled = True

class Vec(RelativeLayout):
    """ This is green area
    I want the button to disable when the green area is clicked.
    """
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            Sec.ids.secbut.disabled = True

class runner(App):

    def build(self):
        self.area = Area()
        return self.area

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runner().run()
```

'''
...

runner.kv

...

'''kivy

```
<Area>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0.9,0.9,0.9,1
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size    
    Sec:
    Vec:


<Sec>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.5
    pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0.9,0.8,0.7,1
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size    
    Button:
        id:secbut
        text:"click"
        size_hint:0.5,0.5

<Vec>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.5
    pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0.5}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0.2,0.8,0.1,1
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size
```

'''

I couldn't find how to solve addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the touch actually collides with the area you care about.

```
if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
    self.ids.secbut.disabled = True
```

Comment: thanks but i'm getting a warning.
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
Green area in one class, button is in other class.

Comment: In your `on_touch_down()` method in `Vec`, you must use an instance of `Sec` to access the `ids`, but you are using the class, not an instance.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I understand, but I don't know how. I'm new on this page.
I'm learning Pthon myself..

Answer (score 0):

Kind of awkward, but you can do it by adding an `id` to your `Sec` like this:

```
<Area>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0.9,0.9,0.9,1
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size    
    Sec:
        id: sec
    Vec:
```

Then use that in your `on_touch_down()` in `Vec`:

```
class Vec(RelativeLayout):
    """ This is green area
    I want the button to disable when the green area is clicked.
    """
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            App.get_running_app().root.ids.sec.ids.secbut.disabled = True
```